# Proof of finite basis theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We say a finite abelian group $G$ is decomposable if there are elements $a_1,\dots ,a_n \in G$:

(D1) For any $x\in G$ ther exist integers $l_1,\dots , l_n$ such that $a_1^{l_1}\cdots a_n^{l_n}=x$.

(D2) if $a_1^{l_1}\cdots a_n^{l_n}=e$ then $a_1^{l_1}=\cdots = a_n^{l_n}=e$.

We then write $G =[a_1,...,a_n]$.
Now if $H$ is a finite abelian group such that every element of $H$ has order a power of a prime $p$, where $a$ has the biggest order of all the elements, how to show that $H/\langle a\rangle=[\langle a\rangle b_1,...,\langle a\rangle b_n]$?

I think D1 follows because the cosets form a partition, and therefore every element $x$ in $H$ should be in some coset $Hb_i$ from which it follows that $Hb_i=Hx$, D2 is more difficult because I do not see how to prove it with these $b$'s. I see the resemblance to the linear independence definition in linear algebra, but my attempts to prove it by contradiction have yielded nothing. How can I show that $H$ is decomposable?